I'm getting an error using Tequila API (error 403). How can I remedy this?
I've been trying to get Tequila API working for a project, and I'm running into a 403 error.
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://api.tequila.kiwi.com/v2/flights_multi

I've checked my API key, it is correct.
I've tried using the API key as a parameter instead (end up getting error 400), I've tried removing the other two header parameters (Content-Encoding and Content-Type), and I've looked over the "requests" parameter for any errors. I've also tried using both json and params in the post request.
Here is the tequila API code documentation I've been using:
General Info: https://tequila.kiwi.com/portal/docs/user_guides/search_api__general_information_
Multicity API: https://tequila.kiwi.com/portal/docs/tequila_api/multicity_api
Here is my code:

import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from monthdelta import monthdelta
import os

# Flight Search endpoint and API key.
FLIGHT_SEARCH_ENDPOINT = "https://api.tequila.kiwi.com/v2/flights_multi"
FLIGHT_SEARCH_API_KEY = os.environ.get("FLIGHT_SEARCH_API_KEY", "Please provide a FLIGHT_SEARCH_API_KEY.")

# City to fly from. We'll use London for this example.
FLY_FROM = "LON"

# Constants for dates tomorrow and six months from tomorrow (our flight date range).
TOMORROW = str((datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
SIX_MONTHS = str((datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1) + monthdelta(6)).strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))

# List of IATA codes for cities to get flight info.
# In order: Paris, Berlin, Tokyo, Sydney, Istanbul, Kuala Lumpur, New York City, San Francisco, Cape Town.
iata_codes = ["PAR", "BER", "TYO", "SYD", "IST", "KUL", "NYC", "SFO", "CPT"]


# This class is responsible for talking to the Flight Search API.
class FlightSearch:

    def __init__(self):

        self.header = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "apikey": FLIGHT_SEARCH_API_KEY,
            "Content-Encoding": "gzip"
        }

        request_list = []

        for code in iata_codes:
            request_params = {
                "fly_to": code,
                "fly_from": FLY_FROM,
                "date_from": TOMORROW,
                "date_to": SIX_MONTHS,
                "adults": 1
            }
            request_list.append(request_params)

        self.params = {"requests": request_list}

        self.response = requests.post(url=FLIGHT_SEARCH_ENDPOINT, headers=self.header, json=self.params)
        self.response.raise_for_status()
        print(self.response.text)

flight_search = FlightSearch()

I've written above what I tried. I'm expecting a 200 return, to get the required data. Thanks for the help!

It is clear from the error message that your API Key doesn't have access on the flights_multi endpoint resource. When you're saying your API key is correct, did you test it against this endpoint and it is returning valid result? Also you can check your API key here - https://tequila.kiwi.com/portal/docs/tequila_api/multicity_api and see if you are getting a valid response.

As stated on the Kiwi.com media blog, from 30 May 2024 the API will only work for B2B partners. It is no longer even possible to register new accounts, unless you are chosen as an affiliate partner. You can read the post here. Log in with your credentials and check if you have access to the B2B portal.
